# Database design for many to many relationship with optional columns?

Tags: laravel, database-design

I have a database relationship with two tables, courses and modules. A course can have many modules and a module can belong to many courses. The admin is able to add modules to a course. But now we have a problem, even though you can have:

```
- Course 1
     module 1 | 3 credits
     module 2 | 4 credits
```

There can be a situation where the modules can be optional but a student has to do one of them:

```
- Course 1
   module 3 | 2 credits OR module 4 | 2 credits
```

So you'll see in the first scenario the student has to pick both those modules to get the credits for the the course, but in the second scenario the student can pick module 3 or module 4 to earn the 2 credits.

So my problem is I have no idea how to form the the relationship between the courses and the modules now that some modules can be optional but one is at least required.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but I can't quite envisage the structure. Where exactly are credits declared - are they directly associated with the module? With many to many relationship the link is made via intermediate table - as @Matthias S mentioned and you can have as many or as little cross referencing records as you wish. Do credits in any way determine how many modules given course needs to have?

Comment: Credits is just a property of modules @SebastianSulinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an intermediate table to realize the `many to many` relationship.
Within this intermediate table you could add a column to specify whether or not the course is `optional`.

But in the end it will be up to you, within the application, to make sure that the student chooses at least one module if mandatory.

You could have something like:

`courses: id, name`

`modules: id, name`

`course_module: id, course_id, module_id, optional`

Your Model would then look like this:

```
class Course extends Model
{
    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Module::class)->withPivot();
    }
}
```

And you would check whether or not a module is mandatory by checking

```
$course->modules->first()->pivot->optional;
```